# CSS and HTML horizontal scrolling in line

Tags: css, scrollbar

so I am trying to customize a script for FiveM and it uses HTML, JS and CSS to display a UI.

I am trying to get it so that the game on this switch is horizontally scrollable rather than stacking underneath.

This is the code for the body

```
<body>
    <div id="wolf-nintendoswitch">
        <img id="ns-swt" src="images/switch.png">
        <div id="ns-blocks">
            <div id="ns-infoArea">
                <b id="ns-infoText" >12:00</b>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-wifi"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-battery-half"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="ns-games">
                <div onclick="openGame('gta')" class="games">
                    <img src="images/games/gta.png">
                </div>
                <div onclick="openGame('bird')" class="games">
                    <img src="images/games/bird.png">
                </div>
                <div onclick="openGame('mario')" class="games">
                    <img src="images/games/mario.png">
                </div>
                <div onclick="openGame('subway')" class="games">
                    <img src="images/games/subway.png">
                </div>
                <div onclick="openGame('snake')" class="games">
                    <img src="images/games/snake.png">
                </div>
                <div onclick="openGame('flip')" class="games">
                    <img src="images/games/flip.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div onclick="closeGame()" id="ns-power">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-power-off"></i>
            </div>
            <img id="ns-console" src="images/icon.png">
            <div id="ns-stick"></div>
            
        </div>
        <div id="ns-gameArea">
            <div onclick="goHome()" id="ns-home">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

can someone help me with this?

[This is what it is currently doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krGBn.png)

EDIT--------------

I have got a scrollbar to show up via CSS but I cant get it to actually scroll.

This is the CSS

```
#ns-games{
position: relative;
width: auto;
height: 40%;
top:20%;
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

[What its now doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP8VB.png)

Comment: What browser engine is there under the hood? Can you try with just: `display: flex: overflow: auto`?